# CRON job doesn't work when executed through command line in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, cron, doctrine-orm

I am currently trying to perform a CRON job by executing a command in terminal. But it throws the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function has() on a non-object in /MyProject/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php on line 161
```

This is my code in the Command file.

```
namespace MyProject\UtilityBundle\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;



    class projectOngoingCommand extends Command
    {
        protected function configure()
        {
            $this
                ->setName('projectOngoingEstimation:submit')
                ->setDescription('Submit Ongoing Project Estimation')

                ;
        }

        protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
        {

           ;
            $projectController= new \MyProject\ProjectBundle\Controller\DefaultController();  


             $msg = $projectController->updateMonthlyOngoingAllocation();


            $output->writeln($msg);
        }
    }
```

This is my code in the default controller.

```
// cron job code
    public function updateMonthlyOngoingAllocation() {

              $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $project = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyProjectEntityBundle:Project')
                    ->getAllOngoingProjectList();
       return "hello";
      }
```

This method is called successfully using the command

`sudo php app/console projectOngoingEstimation:submit`

But it throws the error in the very first line. i.e.

```
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
```

when I tried to call the function from another Action method within the controller it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you use the right strategy here. You try to call your Controller in your command, and according to the error message you have it does not seem to be a good idea.

You should create a service and call this service inside your Controller and your Command.

```
class ProjectManager
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function updateMonthlyOngoingAllocation() {
        $project = $this->em->getRepository('MyProjectEntityBundle:Project')
                ->getAllOngoingProjectList();
        return "hello";
    }    
}
```

and then in the config.yml

```
services:
    project_manager:
        class: MyBundle\Manager\ProjectManager
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Now you can call this service:

- from your controller with `$this->get('project_manager')->updateMonthlyOngoingAllocation()`
- From your command (if your class extends from `ContainerAwareCommand` instead of `Command` ) with `$this->getContainer()->get('project_manager')->updateMonthlyOngoingAllocation()`

Answer (score 0):

You have just do following. No need to inject anything, since console is container aware.

```
 public function updateMonthlyOngoingAllocation() {
                  $project = $this->getContainer()
                           ->get('doctrine')
                           ->getRepository('MyProjectEntityBundle:Project')
                           ->getAllOngoingProjectList();
           return "hello";
          }
```